# Model selection of the nested linear-nonlinear Poisson

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, model-evaluation, likelihood, nested-models

I want to fit the nested linear-nonlinear Poisson models to the spike train of a neuron. How can I test the model performance by computing how much the log likelihood increase from a fixed mean firing  rate model? i.e., what test can I use to see if the increase was significant? Is it possible to use the one-sided signed rank test? If yes, how?